# If subset of poset contains a maximal element then it has a maximum.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

I have an exercise question:-

There is a poset $(P,\sqsubseteq)$ and $X$ is a subset of $P$

(1) to prove that if $X$ contains two (different) maximal elements then $X$ has no
maximum.

(2) Prove that if $(\forall x,y : x,y \in X : x \sqsubseteq y \lor y \sqsubseteq x )$ and if $X$ contains a maximal element then $X$ has a maximum.

---

My Attempt for (1)

Suppose $X$ has a maximum $m$.

$m_i \in X \Rightarrow  m_i \sqsubseteq m  \qquad \{m$ is maximum of $X\}     $

We know $m \in X \Rightarrow \neg (m_i \sqsubset m)  \qquad \{m_i$ is maximal$\}     $

So from both these we conclude $\Rightarrow m_i=m$ which is a contradiction because $m_1 \neq m_2$

So $m_1=m=m_2$

---

Can anybody crosscheck my attempt and guide me through the (2)

Comment: For (1) I guess you should start by saying let $m_1$ and $m_2$ be maximal elements ..  Otherwise it seems to be correct. For (2) suppose that $m$ is a maximal element of $X$ and that $x$ is in $X$ by assumption either $x\sqsubseteq m$  or $m \sqsubseteq x$. By maximality $m \sqsubseteq x$ is equivalent to $m=x$ and hence $m$ is the maximum. (Also replace $mi$ by $m_i$ on line three of your attempt).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, also I have edited as per your suggestion. I will try to frame the answer using your feedback.

Comment: @Nex I have a query here, If we are able to show that $m=x$ just by maximality then why do we need $x \sqsubseteq m$ or $m \sqsubseteq x$.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more clear. Since by maximality $m \sqsubseteq x$ is equivalent to $m=x$ it follows that $x \sqsubseteq m \lor m \sqsubseteq x$ is equivalent to $x \sqsubseteq m$